# How to make constraint permanent once disabled?

Tags: scripting, armature, constraints

I have got a beautiful bone constraint:

[image]

I would like to be able to enable and disable this constraint **without the bone reverting to the original position**.

By default, the bone appears to return to it's *original starting position* when influence is set to 0 or visibility is set to off.

So, for example:

- Constraint is "on" or "enabled" - bone follows Hand.L as expected
- Constraint is "**off**" - bone stays where it is at this exact moment and **does not move**.

I would like to be able to 'apply' the constraint without actually deleting the constraint, as I am intending to turn it on and off frequently during animation.

Comment: Hit the X to the right of influence slider.  It "applies" the constraint and sets influence to 0

Comment: @batFINGER I can't believe I didn't see that. Seems to work!

Comment: Note it may change behaviour when setting influence back to 1 since there is a new location / rotation etc depending on constraint.

Comment: @batFINGER It might be a little off-topic now, but I'm also trying to do this with a script. If I set the influence directly, Blender will show me the code in the bottom left of the 'scripting' tab to type to change it, however when I hit the X button nothing shows up at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disable and Keep Transform**

[Hit the X to the right of influence slider. It "applies" the constraint and sets influence to 0](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231511/15543)

Script Equivalent, copy the transform, ie the world matrix, set the constraint influence to zero (disable) and reset the matrix world.

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object
constraint = ob.constraints.get("Copy Location")
if constraint:
    mw = ob.matrix_world.copy()
    constraint.influence = 0
    ob.matrix_world = mw
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, it's a great help. One last question - since I have to do this for bones, how do I set the matrix_world? `bone.matrix_world = mw` seems to with objects, but not with bones.

Comment: The pose bone matrix eg `context.active_pose_bone.matrix` is akin to the object matrix world for pose bones.

Answer (score 3):

There is button here. look -

[image: button to apply constraint in blender]

because the button looks like a cross, its purpose is not obvious. I myself have hardly noticed this.

After applying it will look like this:

[image: constraint after applying]

Comment: Thank you! this truly is one of the most questionable UI design decisions Blender has had. I completely glossed over this "button" because I thought it must mean instantly zeroing out the Influence or something... I never even hovered over it to check what it actually does. Wow.