# Clear "Child Of" Constraint but keep Location?

Tags: constraints

I want to remove a constraint but I want the object to say in the same position.  If I delete the constraint the object pops back to its original position.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Shift+S and use the 3D cursor as a temporary marker

Comment: Definite works for location, but I also want to keep rotation

Comment: see my answer here, you can create a keyframe > LocRotScale: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24581/changing-childof-constraint-influence-to-0-but-keeping-the-position-it-had-as-a

Comment: Nowadays, as  dr.Sybren points out in another answer to @moonboots ' link, there's a [convenience button](https://imgur.com/a/ZllFdgb) for this.

Comment: @Robin Betts  I don't understand how this button works, maybe give an answer here with this solution? (or extend dr.Sybren's answer?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @dr.Sybren  points out [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/204165/35559), Since Blender 2.8, there's been a convenience button to disable the constraint, while attempting to maintain the World transform of the constrained object (barring interference from other dependencies):

[image]

If you press that, and *then* delete the constraint, the object should stay where it is. To maintain through animation,(you can't delete the constraint,) both the Influence and the constrained object's LocRotScale should be keyed across the transition.

Prior to this, another route would have been:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Apply Visual Transform (Don't Panic..)
2. In the constraint, 'Set Inverse' (Phew!)
3. Delete constraint

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170825/how-to-make-constraint-permanent-once-disabled

Comment: @batFINGER Cheers! Missed it.

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what I was hoping for.  Thanks so much Robin.