Animation - temporary parent
During an animation, I want to move "Object A" along a path and at some point attach"Object B" to "Object A" before releasing "Object B" further down the path.
The methods i have tried is to parent (keep transform) and key the beginning and the end, and also the next frame as i remove the parent. I have also tried both the "Child to" and "Copy location" constraints, but with the same result.
The problem I face is that as soon as i remove the parenthood, "Object B" instantly moves back to the position it had when parenting it with "Object A".
Is there a way to make "Object B" stick to "Object A" and still has it´s own transform changing together with the parent, so that the animation is intact after relasing "Object B" from it´s parent?
I can probably solve the problem using an empty that i can transition to using "Child of" but that seems very messy, since Object B wont move after it has been dropped of.
Thanks in advance!

Related.. (if it works for you, possibly duplicate) : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231511/35559

there is also an add-on which can do that. i think it's called dynamic parent

I have seen that other question, but it did not help - the dynamic_parent add-on was all i needed :)

You can do it with the Dynamic Parent addon by Roman Volodin. You can also do it manually (the addon only automatizes this process):
Give a Child Of constraint to the child, at the beginning of the timeline (frame A) keyframe the Influence at 0:

At frame B move the parent towards the child, keyframe the Influence again at 0:

At frame B+1 keyframe the Influence at 1:

Move the parent and keyframe it at frame C:

At frame C-1 keyframe the Location/Rotation/Scale of the child and keyframe the Child Of Influence at 1:

At frame C keyframe the Visual Location of the child:

And also keyframe the Influence at 0, don't pay attention to the jump of the object:

At frame D move the parent away and keyframe it:


Thanks for your suggestion! I tried your example several times to no avail, but the addon worked like a charm :P

I've edited, I just forgot to keyframe the Location before keyframing the Visual Location, it should be good now   ;)
